# Div's scroll bar disappears on Android

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'm having an issue with how to style a div so that when there's an overflow, the scrollbar displays only if necessary, but **always** when necessary.

The problem I face is that the behavior is different when looking at it in my browser, and both simulating and using an actual Android device.

---

## What I want

[This page on PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/UseLegibleFontSizes) has the exact behavior I'm looking for. It displays a scrollbar that's always visible when needed, and hides it completely when it's not needed.

Screenshot on Android : Scrollbar is always visible because of the overflow
[image: Screenshot on Android : Scrollbar is always visible because of the overflow]

Screenshot on desktop : No scrollbar at all
[image: Screenshot on desktop : No scrollbar at all]

---

## What I have

Currently, the behavior is ok on desktop. There's a scrollbar when needed, and it hides when unneeded.

But on Android, the scrollbar is only visible **while** the user is scrolling, and disappears as soon as it's released. Here's what it looks like :

Android : Overflow, but no scrollbar on the bottom. It should be visible !
[image: Android : Overflow, but no scrollbar on the bottom. It should be visible !]

Android : User is currently pressing the div to scroll, and the bar appears. (It's the black rectangle on the bottom left)
[image: Android : User is currently pressing the div to scroll, and the bar appears. Ok.]

Android : User releases the div in the middle, and the scrollbar disappears again. Not intended, it should be visible !
[image: Android : User releases the div in the middle, and the scrollbar disappears again. Not intended, it should be visible !]

### Example

The live page I'm working on is here : https://www.protectator.ch/post/infinite-download-javascript but I've put a minimal working example in the next section if you want to look at fewer code.

---

## What I tried

I read some SO posts about scrolls, but none I found applies to that specific situation. I've tried looking at the page [I mentioned earlier](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/UseLegibleFontSizes) that works the way I'd like, and I **cannot find** what CSS property I'm missing to reproduce that behavior.

Here is a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem I have with the relevant HTML and CSS (Run it on mobile or in dev mode to see the mobile-like scrollbar and reproduce the problem) :

```css
body {
    width: 250px;
}

pre {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<body><pre><code class="language-html" data-lang="html"><span class="nt">&lt;script </span><span class="na">src=</span><span class="s">"script.js"</span><span class="nt">&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;a</span> <span class="na">id=</span><span class="s">"link"</span> <span class="na">download=</span><span class="s">"file.txt"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>Download !<span class="nt">&lt;/a&gt;</span></code></pre></body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at Google's page more and more, I found my answer.

So first, I found out that the CSS responsible for this is not visible in Chrome dev tools. The part that actually styled the scrollbars was in a separate `<style>` element on the page, and some elements seems to be required to always display the scrollbar when needed. Here is the same minimal example, modified to showcase what's needed :

```css
body {
    width: 250px;
}

pre {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    font-size: 90%;
}

pre::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 12px;
}

pre::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<body><pre><code class="language-html" data-lang="html"><span class="nt">&lt;script </span><span class="na">src=</span><span class="s">"script.js"</span><span class="nt">&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;a</span> <span class="na">id=</span><span class="s">"link"</span> <span class="na">download=</span><span class="s">"file.txt"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>Download !<span class="nt">&lt;/a&gt;</span></code></pre></body>
```

If either the `pre::-webkit-scrollbar` has no defined height, or the `pre::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` has no style, the bar will not show. I think that's because when changing scrollbar's style, the default style has most default values at zero, making no visible parts.

So to make it work, the minimal styles to add to an scrollable element are :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 12px; /* At least not zero */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3); /* Or any other instruction making the element visible */
}
```